# "TWinControl.DoExit" not executed on focus loss by Parent change

Tags: delphi, focus, delphi-10.2-tokyo, lost-focus

I wonder why `TWinControl.DoExit` is *not* executed when the control loses focus because its `Parent` is changed.

What intentional reasons might be for that?

I created the following example to show the behaviour in question:

**CM_EXIT.dfm** (yes, that's it):

```
object Form1: TTestForm
end
```

**CM_EXIT.dpr**

```
program CM_EXIT;

uses Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.StdCtrls;

{$R *.dfm}

type
  TTestForm = class(TForm)
  strict private
    Button: TButton;
    Edit: TEdit;
    procedure EditEnter(Sender: TObject);
    procedure EditExit(Sender: TObject);
    procedure EditKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
  public
    procedure DoCreate; override;
  end;

procedure TTestForm.DoCreate;
begin
  inherited;

  AutoSize := True;

  Button := TButton.Create(Self);
  Button.Align   := alTop;
  Button.Parent  := Self;

  Edit := TEdit.Create(Self);
  Edit.Align      := alTop;
  Edit.Parent     := Self;
  Edit.OnEnter    := EditEnter;
  Edit.OnExit     := EditExit;
  Edit.OnKeyPress := EditKeyPress;
end;

procedure TTestForm.EditEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Button.Caption := 'ENTER called';
end;

procedure TTestForm.EditExit(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Button.Caption := 'EXIT called';
end;

procedure TTestForm.EditKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  Button.Caption := 'EXIT expected';

  Edit.Parent := nil; // focus is lost but 'Exit' won't be called
  Edit.Parent := Self;
end;

var
  Form1: TTestForm;
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskBar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TTestForm, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

When you click inside `Edit`, `EditEnter` gets executed and prints "ENTER called" onto the button.
When you click on `Button` afterwards, `Edit` loses the focus and `EditExit` is executed and prints "EXIT called" onto the button.
On the other hand, when `Edit` has focus and some key (except <kbd>TAB</kbd>) is pressed, `EditKeyPress` prints "EXIT expected" onto the button and changes `Edit.Parent` (in this order), but `EditExit` won't be executed.

Please note that the behaviour is just the same, when `Edit.Parent` is set to some other non-`nil` control.

Comment: Changing a control's parent is not a normal way of using controls. That's probably the reason why it doesn't lose the focus when it happens.

Comment: Probably/possibly because the `WM_KILLFOCUS` message addressed to `Edit1` is thrown away by the form since the `Edit1` window is not among its childs. But a more important question is, what is the real situation that led into this question?

Comment: @yberk: as they always told me: "Use the Source, Luke". Beats me why though, because my name is not Luke.

Comment: As @Tom said: where do you think the WM_KILLFOCUS message should come from, if you change parents? Why on earth do you change parents of an Edit anyway?

Comment: ISTM that if you are deliberately changing your Edit control's parent, you should handle whatever you were expecting its DoExit to do.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis it looks like the `WM_KILLFOCUS` message is arriving at `Edit1` as expected, but the Form will not notify  `Edit1`with the `CM_EXIT` message (that message is where the event is triggered from).

Comment: @nil: thanks for looking. At that time I had no Delphi available.